# How to find last occurrence of a number in a string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Using Ruby... given the following string:

```
x = "blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk"
```

How do I remove all text after the last number/digit?

I thought the easiest way to do this might be by finding the index of last occurrence and then removing everything after that index.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to obtain that index.  All my attempts at using regex have failed.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are answers how to do what you need

Also to find last occurence of number:

```
x = 'blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk'
x.rindex(/\d/)
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason that didn't work I tried it... I must have has my syntax slightly incorrrect.
Combining this with gsub worked beautifully.

Answer (score 4):

This may be the regex you're looking for:

```
s/\D*$//
```

This regex matches all non-digits at the end of the string, starting from the last digit or the start of the string (if it doesn't contain any digits at all), and removes whatever is matched. More precisely, `\D*` is a [greedy](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Greedy.html) match for as many non-digits as possible (zero or more). `$` represents the end of the string.

In Ruby you can use the [gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817) method of a string to search and replace using a regular expression:

```
x = 'blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk'
y = x.gsub(/\D*$/, '')
```

For more info on regexes and Ruby, see [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html).

Comment: You probably just want /\D+$/ (or /\D+\Z/) -- the OP wanted to strip off non-digits from the end.

Answer (score 2):

All in all this seemed to be the cleanest & simplest way to do what I needed. Thank you all for pointing me in the right direction!

```
index = file.rindex(/\d/)
if(index) then
    p file[0 , index+1]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
(.*(?=\d)\d)[^\d]*$
```

You should use something like:

```
result = your_text.gsub(/(.*(?=\d)\d)[^\d]*$/, '\\1')
```

Explanation:

- `(.*(?=\d)\d)` is the group of thing you want to save

  - `.*` the `.` is everything except a line break, the `*` means 0 or more times
  - `(?=\d)` means *until you are able to match* a `\d` which is a digit
  - `\d` means match that digit also!
- `[^\d]+$` is the part you don't want to save

  - in `[^\d]*` matches anything that doesn't match `\d` and the `*` is again 0 or more times
  - the `$` is the end of the line

An alternative could be simply replacing `[^\d]+$` with nothing

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to include the last ']' after the number

Here is my answer:

```
Original_Text = "blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk"
Result___Text = Original_Text.gsub(Regexp.new("(.*\\[[0-9]+\\])[^0-9]*$"), '\1')
puts Result___Text
```

If not, try this:

```
Original_Text = "blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk"
Result___Text = Original_Text.gsub(Regexp.new("(.*[0-9]+)[^0-9]*$"), '\1')
puts Result___Text
```

Comment: variable names with a LeadingCapital are considered constants in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):068:0> "blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk".match(/(.+\d)/)[1]
=> "blah_blah.do.dah[4543"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk"[/.*\d+/]
#returns "blah_blah.do.dah[4543"
```

using rindex:

```
x = "blah_blah.do.dah[4543]junk_junk"
x.rindex(/\d/)
puts "#{$`}#{$&}"
#also returns "blah_blah.do.dah[4543"
```